# How can i highlight a particular item on selection in a navigation tree

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Here is my code for the tree navigator:

```
<b onclick="Toggle('xproducts');"><a id="xproducts">[+]</a>Products</b><br>
   <a >Product List</a><br>
   <a >Order List</a><br>
   <a ID="xspecs" onclick="Toggle('xspecs');">[+]</a>Specifications<br>
   <a >Old Products</a><br>
   <a >New Products</a><br>
```

On selecting the items like "Product List" or "Order List"..., how i can highlight the text with a box.

Comment: Can you define this _how i can highlight the text with a box_ ?

Comment: onClick of "Product List", the text product list needs to be covered with a box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, count = anchors.length; i < count; i++) {
    if (!anchors[i].onclick) {
        anchors[i].onclick = function() {
            this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: red');
        }
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michasko/5cmykajt/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply with the `jquery` plugins .

A nice examples below ,

- [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/demo/)
- [Nestable](http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/)

And more [here ..](http://webrevisions.com/jquery-plugins/8-best-jquery-tree-view-plugin/)